# Where is the implementation of the filter() method in the Stream<T> interface?

Tags: java-8, abstract, java-stream, java

```
class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        myList.add(7);
        myList.add(18);
        myList.add(10);
        myList.add(24);
        myList.add(17);
        myList.add(5);

        Stream<Integer> stream = myList.stream();

        stream = stream.filter(n -> n > 10); // it returns a stream of elements more than 10

        stream.forEach(n -> System.out.print(n + " "));
    }
}
```

This code filters the invoking stream and then prints all the elements that are more than 10. The test method in the Predicate does that for us.

But where is the actually implementation for the filter() method that does return the "STREAM" that is more than 10? That I don't understand.

This question in some way also applies for the forEach() method. How does it iterate through the stream? Since filter() and forEach() methods are abstract in the interface stream and have no implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[java.util.stream.ReferencePipline](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#l159) implements [Stream<T>.filter()](http://download.java.net/lambda/b69/docs/api/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```
@Override
public final Stream<P_OUT> filter(Predicate<? super P_OUT> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    return new StatelessOp<P_OUT, P_OUT>(this, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
                                 StreamOpFlag.NOT_SIZED) {
        @Override
        Sink<P_OUT> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<P_OUT> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedReference<P_OUT, P_OUT>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void begin(long size) {
                    downstream.begin(-1);
                }

                @Override
                public void accept(P_OUT u) {
                    if (predicate.test(u))
                        downstream.accept(u);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh The link provided in this answer points to an old, prototype implementation of lambda/streams. `ReferencePipeline` is not part of the standard Java SE 8 API, which is why you can't see it in the javadocs or in Eclipse. The class still exists but it's an implementation-private class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class ReferencePipeline have the implementation for the fileter() method.

Here is the link of Source code:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could also post an example of how to use the `ReferencePipeline`. Otherwise, the answer has very little value